# Для чего нужны escape последовательности в адресах URL?

Tags: html, url

Часто встречаю ссылки записанные в **escape последовательности** с символом процента в качестве отделителя для закодированного символа. Для чего применяется эта технология?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Они применяются для того чтобы передавать специальные символы. например

Нужно передать параметр значение которого `R&D`, если просто дописать его в url

```
url?param=R&D
```

То можно заметить, что значение параметра будет на самом деле `R`, так как `&` служит для разделения параметров.

При использования `escape` же получим строку

```
url?param=R%26D
```

которая отлично передается.

Comment: Думаю стоит упомянуть, что по стандартам url может содержать только некоторые знаки и латинские символы. А Русские по стандарту нельзя и они должны быть закодированы

Comment: @Mike, feel free to change :)